# jQuery post like issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this code for like and dislike for my posts in my blog:

```
$(".p_like").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {

    ids = $(this).find(".pl_id").val();
    t = $(this);

    if ($(this).find(".bi").hasClass("bi-heart-o")) {
      gfd = 'p';
      $(this).find(".bi").addClass("bi-heart");
      $(this).find(".bi").removeClass("bi-heart-o");
    } else {
      gfd = 'm';
      $(this).find(".bi").addClass("bi-heart-o");
      $(this).find(".bi").removeClass("bi-heart");
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "likes.php",
      data: {
        ids: ids,
        k: gfd
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        t.find(".nol").html(result);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

And when I use the code, in some of the post it likes the post and then dislike it.

What is the problem of the code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Any chance you're running the above code more than once?

Comment: throw in a debugger; line and make sure it isn't called twice. I would guess this is a double click issue. Could also be the php code not handling the k:gfd param correctly.

Comment: No , It is just one in the script file and the php file hasn't problem

Comment: May be due to event bubbling the like button receiving click event multiple time

Comment: problem is just with this code the other files hasn't problem

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion made by Paul Swetz above, to confirm whether this code is running more than once per click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
$(".p_like").find(".bi").click(function(){
    ids = $(this).siblings(".pl_id").val();
    t = $(this);
    if($(this).hasClass("bi-heart-o")){
       gfd='p';
       $(this).addClass("bi-heart");
       $(this).removeClass("bi-heart-o");
    }else{
       gfd='m';
       $(this).addClass("bi-heart-o");
       $(this).removeClass("bi-heart");
    }
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "likes.php",
            data: {ids:ids,k:gfd},
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                t.siblings(".nol").html(result);

            }
            });

});
```

and you maybe used this file two time!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery by default query all given selectors ( here `.p_like` ). It's not needed to iterate over them explicitly.

Jquery methods are chanable. after you select one element you could call methods one after another: `$element.addClass(...).removeClass().css(...)`

Also you've leaked three variables: `ids`, `t`, `gfd`. maybe they're got overriten before you send em out to server so declare them to make em private to your event handler function.

```
$('.p_like').click(function() {

  var $t = $(this),
      $bi = $t.find('.bi'),
      $nol = $t.find('.nol'),
      ids = $t.find('.pl_id').val(),
      gfd;

  if ( $bi.hasClass('bi-heart-o') ) {
    gfd = 'p';
    $bi.addClass('bi-heart').removeClass('bi-heart-o');
  } else {
    gfd = 'm';
    $bi.addClass('bi-heart-o').removeClass('bi-heart');
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'likes.php',
    data: {
      ids: ids,
      k: gfd
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      $nol.html(result);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I agree with declaring those variables inside the function. But for the record, in this case, `ids` and `gfd` aren't problems, since they aren't used asynchronously. The problem was with `t`, which is used in the success handler.

Comment: @DavidKnipe, Nice ... Tanx for clarification